# Algoritmo de recomendación ALS de Spark ML retorna items ya vistos

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

La implementación de Spark ML del algoritmo Alternate Least Squares para recomendaciones, produce un modelo que puede aplicarse a los artículos ya vistos (**training.itemCol**, para películas vistas, en el ejemplo siguiente), con el fin de sugerir nuevos artículos (**movieRecs** en el ejemplo). ¿Cómo es posible que el método devuelva **ya vistos** (no nuevos) elementos como parte de los resultados (**userRecs**)?

Traducción realizada con la versión gratuita del traductor www.DeepL.com/Translator

```
als = ALS(maxIter=5, regParam=0.01, userCol="userId", itemCol="movieId", ratingCol="rating",
          coldStartStrategy="drop")

model = als.fit(training)

userRecs = model.recommendForAllUsers(10)
```

Comment: Hola. Por favor, traduce tu pregunta español. Estás en SO en Español y las preguntas en ingles suelen terminar cerradas sin respuesta.

Comment: El titulo también :)